# Pepper robot default image

Tags: pepper

So i followed the guide from Pepper robot portal. That i must add

```
Domain: com.aldebaran.system.tablet
Key: MainActivity
Value: image (default: opengl for the "bubble" view)

Domain: com.aldebaran.system.tablet
Key: MainResourceURL
Value: http://198.18.0.1/apps/app-uuid/path/to/image
```

This to robot preferences, not including the html folder. I did this but it just shows black image. Tried some variations also but it just is not working.

Comment: Do you know what is the format of the default screensaver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database entries are correct.
You must create an application in Choregraphe containing a folder named 'html' with the picture in. Your file path might look like this:

```
logoApp/html/logo.jpg
```

And your MainResurceURL should look like this:

```
http://198.18.0.1/logoApp/logo.jpg
```

For the changes to take effect your must turn your robot off and on, then activate Artificial Life. Notice that certain behaviors will hide your default logo. If the logo is still not showing then try launching an application that does **not** use the tablet. The change in state (solitary->interactive) should refresh the tablet view.

Comment: Is it possible to add MainResourceURL value which does not include IP? IF ip of the robot changes is there way to tell it to take it from local path of the robot?

Comment: If you refer to 198.18.0.1, this is static. It is the IP of the robot relative to the tablet.

Answer (score 3):

you need to place your image in a folder with the name html.

So in your application "app-uuid", create a folder html. Place your image in and write your pref like behind :

```
Domain: com.aldebaran.system.tablet
Key: MainResourceURL
Value: http://198.18.0.1/apps/app-uuid/image.jpg
```

Hint : test on a browser to display your image with ip-robot/apps/app-uuid/image.png . If it works so your url path is good.

Comment: Is it possible to add MainResourceURL value which does not include IP? IF ip of the robot changes is there way to tell it to take it from local path of the robot?

Comment: Tous ip is the link between the tablet and the head of the robot. So it will not change, it's a fix ip.

Comment: How can I test this in a browser? It doesn't looks like that this static IP is reachable from outsite the robot. I can not ping it nor access it via http.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Some other people will get help from it for sure.

My problem was that the picture had to be exactly 1280px X 800px . That is why it did not show up.