# Changing the default animation of the tablet with another animation

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

My question is what is the format of the animation that Pepper's tablet supports as default ones (I want to change the one with the bubbles with some other animation). And what should I put in the `MainActivity` as value (`image`, `opengl`, `video` or something else).

Also what is the format of the default animation - the one with the bubbles?

Reading this [Change default pepper screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495773/pepper-robot-default-image) I have managed to change the default animation to some image. But when I try it with a `.gif` animation one of the following problems occurs:

- If `MainActivity` is `image`: the `.gif` is static - it acts as a image - I haven't expected anything else.
- If `MainActivity` is `opengl`: it plays the default animation, not the new `.gif`.
- If `MainActivity` is `video`: an alert pops up on the tablet telling me 'this video can not be played.'

Here is the link with the `.gif` I have experimented: [link](https://www.google.bg/search?q=gif+1280+x+720&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt95TOpobXAhUkLMAKHSzfBSAQ_AUICigB&biw=1535&bih=683#imgrc=RX_Prw4wOJ29fM:).